# Complex polynomials on unit circle not closed under conjugation

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $T = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1\}$, the unit circle on complex plane, $P(T)$ be the set of polynomials in $T$ with complex coefficients, $C(T)$ the set of continuous functions from $T$ to $\mathbb{C}$. It can be shown that $P(T)$ is not dense in $C(T)$, and all conditions of the complex version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem are satisfied except that $P(T)$ is not closed under complex conjugation. But if $p(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j z^j$, then $\bar p(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n \bar a_j \bar z^j$, where $|z| = |\bar z| = 1$, so $\bar p \in P(T)$. What's the problem here?

Comment: On the unit circle, we have $\overline{z} = z^{-1}$, so $\overline{p}(z) = \sum_{j = 0}^n \overline{a}_j \cdot z^{-j}$, and that is not a polynomial (if $n > 0$), since the exponents are negative.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to take into account the fact that $\overline{z}=z^{-1}$ on $T$. For example, $(z-i)^2$ is a polynomial, but when we take its complex conjugate we get a singularity at $z=i$.

Showing that $p(\overline{z})=\overline{p(z)}$ shows that it's an automorphism of the set. It doesn't show closure.

For the set of polynomials to be closed under complex conjugation, you need to be able to find *some other polynomial* $g(z)$ such that $g(z)=f(\overline{z})=\overline{f(z)}$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier question:  Find a positive integer $n$ and coefficients $a_j, 0 \leq j \leq n$ such that $\overline{z} = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j z^j$.  Once you do that, you will know how to write any polynomial in $\overline{z}$ as a polynomial in $z$.

Spoiler:  You can't.  One way to see this is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}z = 0$ but $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\overline{z} = 1$.  Another way:  the intersection of the holomorphic and antiholomorphic functions is $\{0\}$.